# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \space n^2\int_{0}^{1/n} x^{x+1} dx$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

How do we evaluate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \space n^2\int_{0}^{1/n} x^{x+1} dx\quad ?$$

I know that

$$\lim_{z \to 0+} \space \dfrac{\int_{0}^z x^{x+1} dx}{z^2}=\dfrac12,$$

and I think the asked limit should also be $1/2$ but I can not prove it.

Please help.

Comment: For integer $n$, $n\rightarrow\infty\iff 1/n\searrow0$. In your first limit, set $z=1/n$ and rewrite it so that you can appeal to your known result.

Comment: Besides knowing the $z$ fact are you allowed to use for proving the $n$ limit? If yes, then $\{z_n\}=\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is a specific positive sequence which converges to $0^{+}$, and the proof seems trivial. Or do I miss something obvious?

Comment: Apply L'Hospital's rule once and then use the fact $\lim\limits_{z\to 0+}z^{z} = 1$.

Comment: @David Mitra,achille hui:- Can I substitute $z=1/n$ ?, isn't the asked limit a limit of sequence and the known limit a limit of a function ?

Comment: Yes you can. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=L$, then for any sequence $x_n\rightarrow a$, one has $f(x_n)\rightarrow L$. This is easy to prove from the relevant definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\color{#C00000}{\lim_{x\to0}x^x=1}
$$
and
$$
\color{#00A000}{n^2\int_0^{1/n}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\color{#C00000}{1}\cdot\color{#00A000}{\frac12}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\inf_{x\in[0,1/n]}x^x\right]}\color{#00A000}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[n^2\int_0^{1/n}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right]}\\
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[n^2\int_0^{1/n}x^{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&\le\color{#C00000}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sup_{x\in[0,1/n]}x^x\right]}\color{#00A000}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[n^2\int_0^{1/n}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right]}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{1}\cdot\color{#00A000}{\frac12}
\end{align}
$$
By the Squeeze Theorem, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[n^2\int_0^{1/n}x^{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\frac12
$$

Answer (score 2):

let $F(x)=\int x^{x+1}dx$ then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{n}}x^{x+1}dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(F\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-F(0)\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2F\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\infty.0.$$ Then we get 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{F\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{0}{0}$$ Then using L'Hospital's rule we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).\left(\frac{-1}{n^2}\right)}{\frac{-2}{n^3}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).n}{2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt[n]n}=\frac{1}{2}$$ where $f(x)=x^{x+1}.$

Answer (score 0):

If you develop $x^{x+1}$ as a Taylor series built around $x=0$, you obtain $$x+x^2 \log (x)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ and the integral between the given bounds is then $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{3}
   \log
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{9}\right)+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$ So, the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.